# JavaFX Tables - Adding columns works but no text

Tags: java, javafx

I have searched everywhere (including Youtube videos) and couldn't find an answer.

I have this very simple code that partially works:

```
@FXML private TableView<model.Location> locationsTable;
@FXML ObservableList<model.Location> locationsList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    locationsList.add(new model.Location("123", "123", "123"));
    locationsList.add(new model.Location("321", "123", "123"));
    locationsList.add(new model.Location("abc", "123", "123"));

    System.out.println(locationsList);

    // LocationId Column
    TableColumn<model.Location, String> columnLocationId = new TableColumn<model.Location, String>();
    columnLocationId.setText("ID");
    columnLocationId.setMinWidth(104);
    columnLocationId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Location, String>("locationId"));

    // Address Column
    TableColumn<model.Location, String> columnAddress = new TableColumn<model.Location, String>();
    columnAddress.setText("Address");
    columnAddress.setMinWidth(104);
    columnAddress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<model.Location, String>("address"));

    locationsTable.getColumns().addAll(columnLocationId, columnAddress);
    locationsTable.setItems(locationsList);
}
```

The columns are added. but the text doesn't show up.
I checked up and the array (locationsList) has all the objects.

Here is the Location class:

```
//***************************************** Variables *********************************************
/**Location's Id (key)*/
private final String locationId;  
/**Locations's address*/
private final String address;
/**Locations's description*/
private String description;
/**Locations's assigned vehicle*/
private Vehicle carAssignedToLocation;
/**Reservations associated with location*/
private HashMap<String, Reservation> reservations;
//***************************************** Constructors ******************************************
/**
 * Constructor of Location object with assigned car as null.
 * @param locationId
 * @param address
 * @param description
 */
public Location(String locationId, String address, String description) {
    this.locationId = locationId;
    this.address = address;

    this.setDescription(description);
    this.setCarAssignedToLocation(null);
    reservations = new HashMap<String, Reservation>();
}
```

I'm out of my mind trying to figure this out, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If your `locationId` & `address` are not same with the `SimpleStringProperty` variable names then they won't show up.

Comment: But they are the same. "locationId" is the name in the Location class, same goes for "address"

Comment: Show the model.Location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem.
The Getters in the Location class were set to protected, not public.

Answer (score 0):

try: `locationsTable.getItems().addAll(locationsList);`  instead of `locationsTable.setItems(locationsList);`